# Python websockets ping / pong / keep-alive errors

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a simple script reading messages from a websocket server and I don't fully understand the keep-alive system.
I'm getting two errors with practically the same meaning `sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received` and `no close frame received or sent`.

I am using `websockets` module. link to the [docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/index.html)

I'd like to know when is my job to send a ping or when to send a pong or if I should be changing the timeout to a longer period since I'll be running multiple connections at the same time (**to the same server but a different channel**).

I have tried running another asyncio task which was pinging the server every 10 to 20 seconds AND
replying only after I receive a packet (which in my case can be 1 second apart or I can get a new one the next day. with a normal websocket.ping() and with a custom payload (heartbeat json string `{"event": "bts:heartbeat"}`

One solution I can see is to just reopen the connection after I get the error but it feels wrong.

```
async with websockets.connect(self.ws,) as websocket:
        packet = {
            "event": "bts:subscribe",
            "data": ...,
        }
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(packet))
        await websocket.recv() # reply 
       
        try:
            async for message in websocket:
                tr = json.loads(message)
                await self.send(tr)
                packet = {"event": "bts:heartbeat"}
                await websocket.pong(data=json.dumps(packet))

        except Exception as e:  # websockets.ConnectionClosedError:
            await self.send_status(f"Suscription Error: {e}", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep-alive packets are send automatically by the library (see https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/timeouts.html#keepalive-in-websockets), so there should be no need to do that yourself.

In your case it seems like that the server is not responding to the "ping" by your client in timely manner. This [FAQ entry](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/common.html#what-does-connectionclosederror-sent-1011-unexpected-error-keepalive-ping-timeout-no-close-frame-received-mean) and its recommendation to catch `ConnectionClosed` looks relevant.